# Understanding how to work with "concurrency" in updating vega signals

Tags: vega

I am trying to programmatically manipulate a signal, and I suspect that I have somehow ran into a concurrency bug where the update was ignored

You can run the following snipped in this [vega example (editor)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-1F2sgAEkACJSo1y25eilIwXq4UMo520P6kbOpr3WMW6m0jWYoOpkMAOUjTRjirjKr91sDKb6AwS5Zw0mkOeVvvzSdtjYAmi2wESXR2fXn-QWRQ3TKdHRnOXcR1XcwmA5qi30zHPLpmcAqyd741bEzaN6YzBGnQuwJ7l53x3X19OoGZelfpVNbwfq12Jz2zy+IaDrKsqjketYnvWTKbmW75GrKX58veq6Tsm0HnpKcFNNIiHmshx5roWz7mM2WE4I80hLt+K4Eahvbnkkg63LcVFIWOKH-sRJYskxRL7mx4HdqeXGXvO0rtne7G0Zx6FQCWb5iVGYE1kJUFinJABSTGgZJgl-sJsmQCWZiDiSym-o+RGGSWHiDi6uGHip+lqcGJYDmRYCyi62a6U5llToZ4oABJMZW1H4RBhEBepkDikMHm3FMrF4VJkV0QBsVggl9ymr5FmQU+hkAArboaXIOT+D4FVZMUgkBHkSeFqWqYVMUJDxCVusljn5VFaFtaJO7Xt1lUcQZMVJLBilNC6YUCX51XRcGSQABqDvc-EpXp-n9cGACqjEJbcuVNdti27amHilbuN7mVVfX0VAADq13XvcOmnQtD0ZU99XTXcUxundY0uamT22QlIHA9J43Bk97n-WA0ikvNvUYgAuhoAaQA4ow5Eo1BNFU1SQAAHkTkChKsYiaH0DYvHgACehDIH03C6PjfiQIRkCMxTVPIDTfRlQzzOs6YACOvgTMwQRUBcsBRPAADWTRKKwYhiDz3CEOg8DMHzlS1PU4tgG6dCytsWN-JAYjoIzThNK0mpJpAGC6KrpjsOguglPSONKHjjAE0TSY1KMYjs6H9LtJT1O06YqMbKhsdMyzfRKNwqDB1zKckwgfim50zgE6bzSQAAxG6bqPOkUIAEIXBXRI6vXjwsi6kDoy8mhZ+gwdO6EfiwMgsyoujfWx2INAOAnYDq5rYdgFb9J9ZAI-T-ARQmB0S-r4LyBbxTaem27GtGBcuPcPj1CwE7ZNdy8aCGIbUCZ443NJiv1SEcTsfu57KA3tfaoUgHkdAShYChHZqgJ2nQqZiFcL7I2G9D7bz6Kgo+2xtjd1dlfG+0cY47kjsg3eMcSYCyFonLaAo841BPhnLOOcxB+3IVAAu08KYl2oGXSuoRNAuk0I8eATd+HoGQFCdgj8tB9wHjgZoQ8xAjzHmqCedCoDTx4UoOeC8xBL2-u0Axy8NC4JqLoHQ3AxDyxQfAQuFMI5R0Tto5ALNnGQmwSAbYQA)

The following is incorrect (does not include "GA")

```
VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("select_toggle", true);
VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("select_tuple", {"unit":"","fields":[{"field":"STATE","channel":"x","type":"E"}],"values":["GA"]});
VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("select_tuple", {"unit":"","fields":[{"field":"STATE","channel":"x","type":"E"}],"values":["ID"]});
VEGA_DEBUG.view.runAsync();
```

However the following is correct (the only difference being the forced `runAsync()`

```
VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("select_toggle", true);
VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("select_tuple", {"unit":"","fields":[{"field":"STATE","channel":"x","type":"E"}],"values":["GA"]});
VEGA_DEBUG.view.runAsync();
VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("select_toggle", true);
VEGA_DEBUG.view.signal("select_tuple", {"unit":"","fields":[{"field":"STATE","channel":"x","type":"E"}],"values":["ID"]});
VEGA_DEBUG.view.runAsync();
```

However, I want the signal to only trigger with *both* "GA" and "ID", and not first ["GA"], then ["GA","ID"] --- is there a way to achieve this? In particular, I don't understand why the first solution resulted in the wrong outcome.

Thanks!

Comment: runAsync() runs async so you need to await it if you want it to finish.

Comment: Ok that's a good point, which means that my second solution is actually also wrong---I can add an `await` to it : / but I suppose I still don't know the answer to my original question which was to avoid a run in between?